# kendo treeview template: d.MyFunction is not a function

Tags: function, templates, mvvm, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am using the kendo treeview control (mvvm version). The items are bound to a template that uses functions of the view model.

```
<div id="myTreeView"
         data-role="treeview"
         data-bind="source: MySource"
         data-template="treeview-template">
</div>

<script id="treeview-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <span data-bind="events: { click: MyClickEvent }, css: { active: MyCssFunction(#=item.Id#) }">#: item.Name #</span>
</script>

viewModel.MyCssFunction = function(e) {...};
viewModel.MyClickEvent= function(e) {...};
```

The click event is executed, but the css function throws an error during model binding: **Uncaught type error: d.MyCssFunction is not a function.** If I replace the function by a simple model property (e.g. a boolean), everything works. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems not possible, but you can reference the function in a conditional expression (note that **viewModel** must be added here):

```
# if(viewModel.MyCssFunction(item.Id)) { #
     <span class="active" data-bind="events: { click: MyClickEvent }">#: item.Name #</span>
# } else { #
     <span data-bind="events: { click: MyClickEvent }">#: item.Name #</span>
# } #
```